# Next auth validation access_token in my custom backend server

Tags: next.js

I was trying authentication with next/auth library. So here are the steps i did for Google login with it.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
   
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }: any) {
      if (account) {
        token = Object.assign({}, token, {
          access_token: account.access_token,
        });
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }: any) {
      if (session) {
        session = Object.assign({}, session, {
          access_token: token.access_token,
        });
        console.log(session); //this prints info including the session
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
});
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I am succesfully getting `access_token` inside my session callback, but if I have my own custom backend, how could i send this token to it and verify over there ?

Answer (score 0):

We can put our verification logic in an api route.

We add this method in the file above you shared with us

```
async verifyAccessToken(token) {
    try {
        // api route
        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/auth/verify`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers(),
            body: JSON.stringify({ token })
        })
        const { success, data } = await response.json()

        if (!success) {
            console.log("The token could not be verified!")
            throw data
        }

        return {
            ...token,
            error: "",
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)

        return {
            ...token,
            error: "VerifyAccessTokenError",
        }
    }
}
```

and then modify jwt callback like that

```
async jwt({ token, account }: any) {
    if (account) {
        token = Object.assign({}, token, {
            access_token: account.access_token,
        })

        return await verifyAccessToken(account.access_token)
    }
    return token
},
```

Finally, we add this api route -> /api/auth/verify

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json()

    const payload = {
        token: body.token,
    }

    // your api endpoint to verify the access token
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/auth/verify`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })

    const data = await response.json()

    // you can tweak the response object here
    return Response.json({
        success: res.ok,
        status: res.status,
        data,
    })
}
```